# COMO CALCULAR HORA EN BASE A FECHAS EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, horas

necesito calcular en sql la diferencia en minutos entre dos fechas teniendo en cuenta que las horas que cuentan son las que estan en el rango de 8 am a 6 pm y no incluya domingos. Por ejemplo, hay una solicitud a las 2023-07-22 17:51:32 y se responde a las 2023-07-24 08:08:24 entonces la diferencia en minutos es 16 minutos y no 2297 minutos (que es lo que hace el datediff normal) porque no incluye los minutos fuera del rango. Este problema es mas cuando hay varios dias en la fechas. Este es el código que utilizo

```
CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [fecha_estado_actual]) BETWEEN 2 AND 7 -- 
            THEN
                ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CAST([fecha_inicio_ajustada] AS TIME) < @hora_inicio_laboral THEN @hora_inicio_laboral
                        WHEN CAST([fecha_inicio_ajustada] AS TIME) > @hora_fin_laboral THEN @hora_fin_laboral
                        ELSE CAST([fecha_inicio_ajustada] AS TIME)
                    END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN CAST([fecha_fin_ajustada] AS TIME) < @hora_inicio_laboral THEN @hora_inicio_laboral
                        WHEN CAST([fecha_fin_ajustada] AS TIME) > @hora_fin_laboral THEN @hora_fin_laboral
                        ELSE CAST([fecha_fin_ajustada] AS TIME)
                    END))
            ELSE 0 
            END AS DiferenciaEnMinutos
```

[image: Ejemplo del resultado]

Comment: Va a incluir días festivos?

Comment: Una pregunta, estas convirtiendo un varchar con la fecha a un time o acaso vi mal?

Comment: De donde sacas que son 667 minutos? Parecen solo 17 (9 del sábado y 8 del domingo)

Comment: la idea es no incluir festivos

Comment: los 667 minutos fue un error en mi descripción

Comment: Para mi estas trabajando mal los datos. Si tu fecha esta bien definida y posee el tipo de dato correcto con un DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @DateStart, @DateEnd) obtienes la diferencia que buscas. Si es de tu agrado, [aqui](https://expert-only.com/es/t-sql/diferencia-entre-dos-fechas-sql-server/?expand_article=1) hay documentacion y ejemplos sobre el uso de DATEDIFF.

Answer (score 0):

Este cálculo suele ser algo complejo al no poder usar directamente las funciones temporales porque no usamos días completos. Tenía a la mano una función con la que experimenté hace tiempo, pero puede tener algunos errores así que te recomiendo que hagas distintas pruebas con diferentes rangos de fechas incluyendo mismo día, múltiples días, incluyendo domingos, sin incluir domingos, iniciando en domingo y terminando en domingo.

La función tiene bastantes comentarios, pero si es necesario, podría explicar mejor alguna parte.

```
/*
Autror   : Luis Cazares
Propósito: Regresar los minutos entre dos fechas con hora, calculando únicamente el horario laboral.

Esta función asume que el horario laboral es de 8:00 AM a 6 PM. 
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MinutosActivos] (
    @FechaInicial  datetime, 
    @FechaFinal    datetime
    )
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT ISNULL((((DATEDIFF(dd,@FechaInicial,@FechaFinal)-1) --Obtenemos el número total de días incluyendo domingos
              - (DATEDIFF(wk,@FechaInicial,@FechaFinal)) --Restamos un día por cada domingo
              ) * 600) --Esto nos da todos los días menos uno que completaremos con las operaciones siguientes.
        + (SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,6,@FechaInicial)%7 = 0 
                        THEN 0
                    WHEN @FechaInicial <= DATEADD(MI, 480, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @FechaInicial), 0)) 
                        THEN 600 --Si inicia antes de las 8:00 cuenta como día completo
                    WHEN @FechaInicial >= DATEADD(MI, 1080, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @FechaInicial), 0)) 
                        THEN 0 --Si inicia después de las 18:00 no se cuenta
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(MI, @FechaInicial, DATEADD(MI, 1080, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @FechaInicial), 0))) --Minutos entre el inicio y 18:00
                END
                + CASE WHEN @FechaFinal <= DATEADD(MI, 480, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @FechaFinal), 0))
                            THEN 0 --Si termina antes de las 8:00 no cuenta
                        WHEN @FechaFinal >= DATEADD(MI, 1080, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @FechaFinal), 0))  
                        OR DATEDIFF(dd,6,@FechaFinal)%7 = 0
                            THEN 600 --Si termina después de las 18:00 cuenta como día completo
                        ELSE DATEDIFF(MI, DATEADD(MI, 480, DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, @FechaFinal), 0)), @FechaFinal) --Minutos entre 8am y el fin del rango
                    END
            WHERE @FechaInicial <= @FechaFinal)
    /* Descomentar para usar días festivos
    - ((SELECT count(*)
        FROM DiasFestivos
        WHERE [FechaFestivo] BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal) * 600)
    */    ,0)  AS Minutos;
```

La función la podrías llamar de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT *,
       ma.Minutos AS DiferenciaEnMinutos
FROM MiTabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.MinutosActivos( t.fecha_inicio_ajustada, t.fecha_fin_ajustada) ma;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, revisare esta función